# Text over top of border of div below

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have text appear on the top of a div that has a border that also has a white background so you don't see the border line going through the text. I've tried adding z-index to the text but I believe since `position: relative` it doesn't matter. I'm also open to other suggestions as to how to accomplish and would prefer not to use a `fieldset` and `legend`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks99w7p8/4/)

```css
#large-div-text {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(64, 189, 233, 0.42);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#why {
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="why">
  No line behind me, please!
</div>
<div id="large-div-text">
  Large div text
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right idea about setting a **[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)**. However, note that in order for a `z-index` to apply, you need to specify a **[`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** property other than the default of `static`. That will have your `#why` element sit on top. From here, it's just a matter of giving it a fixed **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** (along with **[`margin: 0 auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)** for alignment) so that the rest of the border gets shown.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
#large-div-text {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(64, 189, 233, 0.42);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#why {
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="why">
  No line behind me, please!
</div>
<div id="large-div-text">
  Large div text
</div>
```

Note that the `width` property denotes just how much of the border is shown - feel free to adapt to suit! If you want it to perfectly wrap around the text, I'd recommend using a **[`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)** tag instead of a **[`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)**.

Comment: one thing to note is I think you need a `div` tag to set the width as you can't set the width on a `span` irc

Comment: Absolutely correct :) A `<span>` tag is simply an inline container and as such does not have a `width` or `height`. The `width` that it *takes up* is denoted by its *content*. That's kind of what meant with my note about the `<span>` being constrained to the width of the text, however I should have explicitly stated that haha ;)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't need to use absolute or z index something.

The div#why is block, you dont want to make it block, instead make it inline-block so it consume it's normal width, not 100%.

The problem now is how you can center the div#why, i used position:relative, and transformX.

Cheers!

```css
#large-div-text {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(64,189,233,0.42);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#why {
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="why">
  No line behind me, please!
</div>
<div id="large-div-text">
 Large div text
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use a position attribute for z-index to work. And you can use a span element to set the background of the text. The span is an inline element ulike div, and will change its width depending on the content.

```css
#large-div-text {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(64, 189, 233, 0.42);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#why {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}

.whitebg {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="why">
  <span class=whitebg>No line behind me, please!</span>
</div>
<div id="large-div-text">
  Large div text
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add some margin

```css
#large-div-text {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(64, 189, 233, 0.42);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#why {
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="why">
  <span class=whitebg>No line behind me, please!</span>
</div>
<div id="large-div-text">
  Large div text
</div>
```